# ReactNative onResponderRelease doesn't work on Android

Tags: react-native

I tried to use ScrollView's  onResponderRelease event on an android device, but it dosen't work fine.  Code like this:

```
<ScrollView 
    onResponderRelease = {()=>{console.log('release')}}
/>
```

I saw many react-native libs used this api like this. 
Does it support android platform ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it has such problem - you can read more about this https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/9447

Try to use 'onMomentumScrollEnd', in some cases it will do exactly what do you expect:

```
<ScrollView 
    onMomentumScrollEnd = {()=>{console.log('release on Android')}}
    onResponderRelease = {()=>{console.log('release on IOS')}}
/>
```